# How can I reduce the water pressure in my shower?

Tags: shower, water-pressure

I just moved into a new apartment on the 2nd floor of a 30 story building. The shower is one of those single-handle types which you turn to change the temperature, but the flow isn't adjustable (unless I'm missing something).

The problem: the pressure is *really* high. On my back it is tolerable but not comfortable. On my face it feels like taking a punch.

I realize half the planet wants stronger water pressure, but I want less. I (obviously) know *nothing* about plumbing, but how do I go about reducing the flow from 'as used by riot police' to 'normal shower'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually people want "less pressure" because the showerhead is laying out an unusually harsh spray.  I've had shower-massage heads for the last 20 years, that are switchable between any of up to a dozen  patterns, and I've found 1 or 2 are always harsher than the others and give that "getting pummeled" feeling but not in a good way.

So the first stop, I would say, is to change the showerhead, which I gather came with the apartment.

The purpose of the single knob is to provide *thermostatic control* so you can set it to a temperature and it will stay there regardless of pressure fluctuations. That's a nice feature, but *their* reason for doing it is to obtain anti-scald protection, which is easy once the thermostatic mechanism is present.  They care about anti-scald because they run the hot water temp high enough either a) to provide anti-legionella protection, or b) also work as district heating, which runs quite hot.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a few different shower heads, bigger ones with more holes.

I would go with a [rain shower](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Glacier-Bay-Modern-1-Spray-8-in-Square-Raincan-Fixed-Showerhead-in-Chrome-56081-X401/206871489) type head.

If that is not enough or you like the current head you can install a [flow control](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Glacier-Bay-Flow-Control-Shower-Push-Button-3075-552/204511124?keyword=375%20713&semanticToken=223t0000111_20191116123216230180_h1wg%20223t0000111%20%3E%20%20cnn%3A%7B0%3A0%7D%20cnr%3A%7B7%3A0%7D%20cnd%3A%7B4%3A0%7D%20cne%3A%7B0%3A0%7D%20cnb%3A%7B9%3A0%7D%20cns%3A%7B5%3A0%7D%20cnx%3A%7B0%3A0%7D%20st%3A%7B375%20713%7D%3Ast%20oos%3A%7B0%3A1%7D%20rt%3A%7B375%20713%7D%3Art%20dln%3A%7B572891%7D%20tgr%3A%7BRelaxed%20match%7D%20qu%3A%7B375%20713%7D%3Aqu) device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a valve between the pipe and shower head. There are inexpensive on/off valves ; about one inch long, chrome , 90 degree turn. They tend to be stiff to turn but you probably only need to adjust it once.